# Does emacs have something like vi's "set number"?

Tags: emacs, editor

Does emacs have something like vi's “set number”, so that each line starts with its line number?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [linum.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/LineNumbers) to your emacs dir / .emacs file.